# How do I add an indentation after creating a new line

Tags: spacing

I am new to Latex, and I am not understanding anyone's comments about formatting. It was my understanding that Latex would help me make documents look however I want them to.
I am going to use Latex for some basic math courses, and I would like to know how to line up my solution apart from the problem number.
This is the code that I am trying to use to create my indentations.

```
\section*{Practice Problems}

 1.2) A is a true statement. \\
 \quad B is a true statement. \newline
 \hspace{2mm} C is a false statement. \newline
 D could be either false or true so it is not a statement. \newline
```

[image: This is the output from the Latex code I have entered, and I would like the statements to line up, and the number to be on the left.]

I would like the result to look like this though. Without the periods.
 1.2) A is a true statement.
 ......     B is a true statement.
 ......     C is a false statement.
 ......     D could be either false or true so it is not a statement.

Comment: you should almost never need manual numbering or `\\ ` or `\newline` or spaces such as `\hspace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this trick `\phantom{1.2)}`.

[image]

```
\section*{Practice Problems}

1.2) A is a true statement. \\
\phantom{1.2)} B is a true statement. \newline
\phantom{1.2)} C is a false statement. \newline
\phantom{1.2)} D could be either false or true so it is not a statement.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an **exam class** in LaTex which handles multiple-choice questions, marks per question, etc

[image: Exam class multiple choice from Overleaf]

```
\question Which of these famous physicists invented time?
    \begin{oneparchoices}
     \choice Stephen Hawking 
     \choice Albert Einstein
     \choice Emmy Noether
     \choice This makes no sense
    \end{oneparchoices}




  \question Which of these famous physicists published a paper on Brownian Motion?
             \begin{checkboxes}
             \choice Stephen Hawking 
             \choice Albert Einstein
             \choice Emmy Noether
             \choice I don't know
            \end{checkboxes}
```

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Typesetting%20exams%20in%20LaTeX#Multiple_choice_questions

http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you employ a two-column `tabularx` environment, with an overall width of `\textwidth`; the second column allows automatic line breaks, if and when needed.

The amount of whitespace between the columns is governed by the macro `\tabcolsep`. Its default value is `6pt`; to reduce that value by one third, you'd issue the instruction `\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env.
\begin{document}

\section*{Practice Problems}

%\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{}}
1.2) & A is a true statement.  \\
     & B is a true statement.  \\
     & C is a false statement. \\
     & D could be either false or true so it is not a statement. 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```